# modifying triangles and vertices on react-three-fiber mesh after render

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, quad, level-of-detail

I'm trying to recreate some old Unity QuadSphere code with a `@react-three/fiber` version, and I've written a quick test that creates a custom class, `QuadGeometry` extending from `THREE.BufferGeometry` in which I generate my vertices and indices. The starting configuration looks something like:

```
6-7-8
|\ /|
3 4 5
|/ \|
0-1-2
```

where 0 through 8 are groups of 3 numbers creating my vertices array which is then added as an attribute using `setAttribute('position', new Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3))` and my indices are `[0,4,2,2,4,8,8,4,6,6,4,0]` which are specified using `setIndex(indices)`. this all works perfectly well and displays correctly. the problem occurs when I go to update the indices so that my quad has activated sides such that it would look like:

```
6-7-8
|\|/|
3-4-5
|/|\|
0-1-2
```

the above change only modifies the indices to be like `[0,4,1,1,4,2...6,4,3,3,4,0]` (more indices for more triangles) and I set these by again calling `setIndex(indices)`, but my mesh isn't updating to reflect the change in faces (indices). I've setup my `mesh` using the following so that it will update the indices every 5 seconds:

```js
export function QuadMesh(props: QuadMeshProps) {
    const meshRef = useRef<Mesh>();
    const [state, setState] = useState<QuadState>('unified');
    const quad = useMemo<QuadGeometry>(() => {
        console.info('creating new QuadGeometry!', {props});
        return new QuadGeometry({
            centre: {x: props.position[0] ?? 0, y: props.position[1] ?? 0, z: props.position[2] ?? 0},
            radius: props.radius ?? 1
        });
    }, [props]);
    let nextChangeAt: number;
    const changeFrequency = 5; // 5 seconds
    useFrame(({ clock }) => {
        const time = clock.getElapsedTime(); // in seconds
        if (nextChangeAt == null) {
            nextChangeAt = time + changeFrequency;
        }
        if (time >= nextChangeAt) {
            nextChangeAt = time + changeFrequency;
            const geometry = meshRef.current.geometry as QuadGeometry;
            setState(modifyQuadGeometry(geometry, state));
        }
    });
    
    return (
        <mesh ref={meshRef} dispose={null} geometry={quad} castShadow receiveShadow>
            <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" wireframe={true} />
        </mesh>
    );
}

function modifyQuadGeometry(geometry: QuadGeometry, state: QuadState): QuadState {
    let outState: QuadState;
    /* update to indices happens here on geometry obj */

    const { position } = geometry.attributes;
    position.needsUpdate = true;
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    return outState;
}
```

so how should I go about triggering an update of the faces / triangles in my mesh?

NOTE:
if I modify the indices before I generate the mesh then it renders with the expected additional faces, but I specifically want to modify it at runtime as this is meant to be used to generate a level of detail effect (eventually).

You can see the code at: https://github.com/bicarbon8/QuadSphere/blob/in-javascript/src/components/shapes.tsx

and a demo at: https://bicarbon8.github.io/QuadSphere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I consider this a bit of a hack, but for the sake of anyone who is trying to do something similar, I managed to get something similar to what I want by forcing the `mesh` to fully re-load and render by adding a `key` property based on the `QuadGeometry` id and active sides and then also creating a recursive function to render all child `QuadGeometry` objects in their own mesh and not rendering a mesh of my `QuadGeometry` if it has any children. the updated code looks like this

```js
export function QuadMesh(props: QuadMeshProps) {
    const [level, setLevel] = useState<number>(0);
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState<number>(1);
    const registry = useMemo<QuadRegistry>(() => {
        console.info('creating new QuadRegistry!');
        return new QuadRegistry();
    }, [props]);
    const quad = useMemo<QuadGeometry>(() => {
        console.info('creating new QuadGeometry!', {props});
        return new QuadGeometry({
            centre: {x: props.position[0] ?? 0, y: props.position[1] ?? 0, z: props.position[2] ?? 0},
            radius: props.radius ?? 1,
            registry: registry
        });
    }, [props]);
    return MeshBufferGeom({quad});
}

function MeshBufferGeom(props: {quad: QuadGeometry}) {
    const meshes = new Array<MeshProps>();
    if (!props.quad.hasChildren()) {
        const positions = new Float32Array(props.quad.vertices);
        const indices = new Uint16Array(props.quad.indices);
        meshes.push(
            <mesh key={`${props.quad.id}-${props.quad.activeSides.join('-')}`} castShadow receiveShadow>
                <bufferGeometry>
                    <bufferAttribute 
                        attach="attributes-position"
                        array={positions}
                        count={positions.length / 3}
                        itemSize={3} />
                    <bufferAttribute
                        attach="index"
                        array={indices}
                        count={indices.length}
                        itemSize={1} />
                </bufferGeometry>
                <meshBasicMaterial attach="material" wireframe={true} />
            </mesh>
        );
    } else {
        meshes.push(...[
            props.quad.bottomleftChild,
            props.quad.bottomrightChild,
            props.quad.topleftChild,
            props.quad.toprightChild
        ].map(c => MeshBufferGeom({quad: c})));
    }
    return (
        <>
        {...meshes}
        </>
    );
}
```

where `MeshBufferGeom` is the recursive function that returns either a single or multiple `<mesh>...</mesh>` elements (if multiple it's all of the child and children's children, etc. mesh objects). I'm still hoping someone can tell me a better way to update the *faces* on an existing `mesh` so I can reduce the number of throw-away objects I'm creating and disposing of each time the `QuadGeometry` activates a side, but for now this will work